# "Electronics and Communications Engineering" equivalent in the U.S.A

Tags: undergraduate, terminology, major

I graduated from a European University with a Bachelor of Science Degree (Engineering Degree) and I'm about to move in the United States.
My specialization/ major would be Telecommunications Engineering.

What is the US equivalent of this ? I've noticed US colleges usually have EE(Electrical Engineering programs), which is the closest I've found.

Comment: For my undergraduate degree in EE from a U.S. institution, a majority (if not all) of the upper-division coursework was in the fields of communications and electronics.

Comment: Are you asking what the equivalent of your *undergraduate* degree would be, or what the *graduate* degree you hope to earn would be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrical engineering and (when it exists) electronics engineering usually cover telecommunications, as well as many other topics. Undergraduate degrees in NA are usually broader in scope than those in Europe.

But it wouldn't try to change the terminology of your own major: keep it as telecommunications engineering if that's what it is, and everyone will understand.

Comment: My University's program is called "Electronics and Telecommunications Engineering". Since I've just graduated, my diploma hasn't been issued.For example, MIT and Harvard offer concentration in EE-CS (Electrical Engineering and Computer Science).

Comment: I wanted to clarify the terminology used in US for career purposes and maybe pursuing a Master's Degree.

Comment: I wouldn't misrepresent your degree. If you say you've graduated with an electrical engineering degree in the US, many people will assume your have done some power engineering, for instance. Use what is written on your diploma, and maybe clarify your coursework in the accompanying documents.

Comment: Also Switzerland puts everything under one hat (electrical engineering and IT or something like that), but within those catch-all degrees, you have a choice of multiple tracks which reflect the various tracks directly offered as degrees in other countries (telecommunications, control, electronics, electrical engineering sensu stricto), or you have greater freedom in choosing coursework (more frequent in the US, but I've seen tracks on their programs too), so there is no real difference. 
When in doubt, in the US it's probably called EE.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you're going to get is Computer Engineering.  Most universities will have classes on networking, but you'll have to look for those with telecom.  Otherwise, if you want to specialize in telecommunications, your best bet is probably a trade school.

Comment: Actually, I intend to apply for Graduate School in Computer Science.

Comment: *if you want to specialize in telecommunications, your best bet is probably a trade school.* - what? There are plenty of academic graduate programs in telecommunications. (And these are not necessarily in computer engineering departments)

Answer (score -1):

Electrical and Electronic Engineering usually refers to building electrical devices like computers, or cellphone networks.

Computer Science usually refers to using computers, especially programming.

I hope this helps clarify some terminology.

Comment: This is not accurate. Electrical engineering does not necessarily involve "building electrical devices" (though it *may* include that) and computer science is much more than "using computers"

Comment: Vastly simplified (of course) in order to emphasise the difference between them. I think both are generally accurate though. If Electrical Engineering is not about building devices it is at least about the theory of building the devices.